# Using hashchange to load dynamic pages not working with secondary nav

Tags: ajax, jquery, dynamic, hashchange

Any ideas on why this won't work. I am using the tutorial from CSS-Tricks using AJAX to load pages dynamically. This works fine up until I introduced a secondary navigation on some pages which caused pages to load normally.

This is the code I am using. I am using classes to style the different nav areas.

```
$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;

$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
    };

});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

});

Website: http://darynjohnson.com/Medical%20Futures/about.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those new created links do not have any events bound to them because u set delagate function on the the object which is not changed. New added objects with the same tag ("nav" here) won't get delagation.

Use:

```
$('#page').delegate("nav a", "click", function() {
  window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
  return false;
});
```

Also I recommend you to upgrade jQuery to the newest version and replace delegate() with on()

Comment: Thank you so much! That's been bugging me for ages

Comment: I'm assuming it's not possible for the page titles to change when switching between pages is it?

Comment: It's possible. You can use pushState method (History.js plugin for crossbrowers functionality) or do it manually by setting `document.title` attribute

Comment: I tried to do it manually but as the source code doesn't change between pages (it just keeps the source code from the page first loaded) it doesn't work. See: http://darynjohnson.com/Medical%20Futures/about.php

Comment: The source code won't change. It displays what was rendered from the server. Why do you want to change the source code?

Comment: Maybe I am just doing it wrong but if you go to http://darynjohnson.com/Medical%20Futures/gallery.php - The title is correct but then if you navigate to this http://darynjohnson.com/Medical%20Futures/gallery.php#about.php - the title doesn't change. Even though I have added <script>
 document.title = "Gallery • Medical Futures";
 </script> to the code

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve but if I understand you correctly setting `document.title` within hashchange handler should do the work

Comment: I just want the titles to change like they would if I wasn't using Ajax to load content. At the moment it just loads the title of the first page you go to then it doesn't change.

Comment: change the title in `.load()` function's callback

Comment: i am loading a view in asp.net mvc on menu button click using the css tricks code in my view jquery charts are used to display chart, page loads fine but chart is not drawn i have written chart drawing code in that view in document.ready function why chart is not drawing?

Comment: It's probably not drawing because loading the view dynamically do not trigger document.ready function